# I want to pass this Dynamic variable Id to Graphql query in react-apollo but it gives error..?

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I want to pass this dynamic id to query which i have got from params instead of writing static number in query

i have tried passing this variable like `${Id}` but it doesnot work for me.

```
let Id = props.match.params.id;
    const GET_PAGES = gql`
{
  singlePost(id:`${Id}`){
    title
    template
    publishdate
    content
    type
    metas

  } 
}
`;
```

I got this error everytime.

```
Line 21:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  19 |     const GET_PAGES = gql`
  20 | {
> 21 |   singlePost(id:`${Id}`){
     |                  ^
  22 |     title
  23 |     template
  24 |     publishdate
```

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: @Ricola i dont know the method to pass thi id variable to query..if i write a static number it gives me the result but i want to pass this variable this dynamic variable whose value changes for every single post..Kindly Please help

Comment: i have edited my question and posted the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apollo Query with Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522902/apollo-query-with-variable)