# How do I do dynamic routing with Next.js based on slug from GraphQL API?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo, apollo-client

I'm having a tough time getting my head around dynamic routing based on variables. I'm able to get a list of items in a collection but not an individual item and its fields for an individual page with a dynamic route with Next.js.

#### Background

I have a KeystoneJS headless CMS with a GraphQL API. I'm trying to create a simple blog with a list of posts and an individual post page. I have been able to query and return a list of posts, but I need to get an individual post based on the slug field so it can be accessed at `/posts/[slug].js`.

#### What I've tried

I've been using Apollo Client to handle the queries. I have an `apolloClient.js` file that connects to the API:

```
// apolloClient.js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

export default new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:3000/admin/api",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

I have a `post.service.js` file to query the API:

```
// post.service.js
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
import apolloClient from "../_utils/apolloClient";

export async function getAll() {
  return apolloClient
    .query({
      query: gql`
        query {
          allPosts {
            id
            term
            slug
          }
        }
      `,
    })
    .then((result) => result.data.allPosts);
}

export async function getBySlug(slug) {
  return apolloClient
    .query({
      query: gql`
        query {
          Post(slug: $slug) {
            id
            title
            lead
            body
          }
        }
      `,
    })
    .then((result) => {
      return result.data.Post;
    });
}
```

And finally, in `posts/[slug].js` I am trying to return the data like so:

```
//[slug].js
import Head from "next/head";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { getAll, getBySlug } from "../../_services/post.service";

export default function Post({ post }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Launchpad</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        <h1>{post.term}</h1>
      </main>
      <footer>
        <p>{post.lead}</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const posts = await getAll();

  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.slug },
  }));

  return { paths, fallback: false };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const post = await getBySlug(params.id);

  return { props: { post } };
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. I must not be passing the variable (which I'm assuming is the slug) into the query properly and having read several tutorials I still can't get my head around it. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Couple of things: 1) in `getStaticPaths` you're saving `await getAll()` to `lingo` but then mapping the `posts` variable, is this a typo? 2) Doing the same in `getStaticProps` for the `getBySlug` call, using the `term` variable but then returning `post`.

Comment: Yes, copied code from the wrong file, thanks. I've updated the code in my original question. I have the same problem. Nothing is coming back.

Answer (score 1):

In `getStaticPaths` the keys returned in the `params` objects need to match the dynamic route naming. In your case, since you're using `posts/[slug].js` for the route, you'd need to return `params` with the format `{ slug: post.slug }`.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const posts = await getAll();

  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { slug: post.slug }, // Rename to `slug`
  }));

  return { paths, fallback: false };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const post = await getBySlug(params.slug); // Rename to `params.slug`

  return { props: { post } };
}
```

**Edit:** Regarding the request issue, the following change to `getBySlug` should make it work as expected.

```js
export async function getBySlug(slug) {
  return apolloClient
    .query({
      query: gql`
        query Post($slug: String){
          post(slug: $slug) {
            id
            title
            lead
            body
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        slug
      }
    })
    .then((result) => {
      return result.data.Post;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my code but I get the error: `Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400`. This suggests my query is wrong in `post.service.js`? Is my argument wrong?

Comment: Yes, that means something's wrong with the request.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll ask a question separately for how to query the API by slug as I have no idea how the query would know what the slug is.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51523848/1870780? Shouldn't you pass an extra `variables` object to `apolloClient.query()` call? Note that my GraphQL knowledge is limited.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it helped me write the query better. I still get an Apollo Error with my query so I've reached out for help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65829744/how-do-i-query-my-api-for-a-single-entity-by-its-slug-with-graphql).