# How do I query my API for a single entity by its "slug" with GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo, keystonejs, dynamic-routing

I am creating a Next.js blog that uses an API created with KeystoneJS. I am *extremely* confused by how I can get an individual post on a dynamic route from the post's slug.

#### The Query

This is how I *thought* the query should be:

```
query Post($slug: String) {
  Post(where: { slug: $slug }) {
    id
  }
}
```

And this was queried like so in a file called `post.service.js`:

```
export async function getBySlug(slug) {
  return apolloClient
    .query({
      query: gql`
        query Post($slug: String) {
          Post(where: { slug: $slug }) {
            id
          }
        }
      `,
    })
    .then((result) => {
      return result.data.Post;
    });
}
```

Unsurprisingly, that causes an ApolloError because how would the query know what slug to query the API for when accessing `posts/[slug].js`?

**It's also worth noting that KeystoneJS say on their guides that:**

> **The single entity query accepts a where parameter which must provide an id.**

How would I pass the post's ID to the query depending on what slug was accessed at `[slug].js` and does this mean I can't query by the slug at all?

On `[slug].js` I am using `getStaticPaths()` and `getStaticProps()` like this:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const posts = await getAll();

  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { slug: post.slug },
  }));

  return { paths, fallback: false };
}
```

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const term = await getBySlug(params.slug);

  return { props: { post } };
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working @Anthony?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `where` clause rather than matching on `id`, you have to query `allPosts` rather than `Post`.

A tested example, matching a user by their email address:

```
query($email: String!) {
  allUsers(where : {email: $email}){
    id
  }
}
```

Variables:

```
{
  "email": "user@email.com"
}
```

So I think you want:

```
query($slug: String!) {
  allPosts(where: {slug: $slug}) {
    id
  }
}
```